# django-DefectDojo postgres user disconnects & reconnects constantly

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

I am running DefectDojo on AWS using a serverless Aurora (Postgres 13.8) DB

I see a large number of connect/disconnect events in the logs. They look like this:

```
2023-10-04 19:44:04 UTC:10.237.120.220(56990):[unknown]@[unknown]:[19442]:LOG: connection received: host=10.237.120.220 port=56990
2023-10-04 19:44:04 UTC:10.237.120.220(56990):postgres@defectdojo:[19442]:LOG: connection authorized: user=postgres database=defectdojo SSL enabled (protocol=TLSv1.2, cipher=AES128-GCM-SHA256, bits=128, compression=off)
2023-10-04 19:44:04 UTC:10.237.120.220(56990):postgres@defectdojo:[19442]:LOG: disconnection: session time: 0:00:00.011 user=postgres database=defectdojo host=10.237.120.220 port=56990
```

The logs are filled with these actions: connection received -> connection authorized -> disconnection. These sessions all last for less than a second.

Is this behavior expected or is this a symptom of an underlying problem with my postgres user connection?

Comment: It might be helpful to include milliseconds in the log messages, if Aurora lets you do that.  Nothing here indicates a problem with PostgreSQL itself, although it might indicate a problem with the application or your connection pooler (if any).  How far apart are the connections from one another?

Comment: The connections vary between 2 and 10 seconds apart from one another.